# Using one mac to publish apps to two developer accounts

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store, itunes-app

I have a ios developer account with my apps and i have a mac that i use for publishing my apps.
My clients wanted me to publish there apps using my mac in to there development account so can i do that if YES how do i do that without getting there appstore id password.

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

Your client has to send those to you:

- Keychain export of the Distribution Certificate and the password used for exporting.
- Distribution Provisioning Profile correctly set up for the exported Distribution Certificate and the App ID of the app to be submitted.
- Access to iTunesConnect as a Technical User.